# How do I execute commands after connecting to telnet in travis-ci?

Tags: github, travis-ci

I want to enter a telnet session to memcached server. Then I want to check stats and quit.
Here is my .travis.yml file:

```yaml
language: c
compiler: gcc

before_install:
  - sudo apt-get install libmemcached-dev
  - sudo apt-get install memcached
  - sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
script:
  - cd TEST
  - memcached -d -u travis -m 128 -p 11211 127.0.0.1
  - chmod +x run_script
  - telnet localhost 11211
after_success:
  - stats
  - quit
```

However the "stats" and "quit" commands are never executed. No matter what I do.

[image: Terminal output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The telnet session does not end, so the `script` step never finished, and the `after_success` does not happen.

The telnet commands need to happen inside of the telnet session. You can use need something like the following "heredoc", to put either in the `script` or `after_success` phase:

```yaml
  - telnet localhost 11211 <<-EOF
      stats
      quit
    EOF
```

Comment: Thanks! I found a way to input commands in stdin of remote virtual host with expect utility.